# NSIS guidelines

Tags: nsis

I want to make my NSIS code more readable.

I need some guidelines regarding writing code section wise (like there is `#region` `#endregion` in C#) or any such information that can make writing NSIS code interesting and easy.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also there is Visual Studio (2008, 2008, 2010 and 2012) addin available called **Visual & Installer**.

It offers a lot of features like syntax highlighting, navigation, (GoTo definition, Goto reference, navigation bars, open file at cursor, ...) also IntelliSense support and much more.

Try here: http://www.unsigned-softworks.sk/visual-installer/

Comment: You state "(2008, 2008, 2010 and 2012)", you mean 2005, 2008,... ? Interesting.

Comment: Yes, exactly: VS 2005 to 2012

Comment: Even Visual Studio 2013 is now supported!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an IDE, you can try with [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) that supports code folding, colorization, `makensis` compilation from the editor and compilation errors parsing. (BTW: Scite is not actually an IDE, but rather a very light yet powerful text editor with built-in support for colorizing and compiling programming languages)

With the latest versions of SciTE, you just need to uncomment the loading of NSIS support that is not enabled by default.

Also, there is the [Development Environments section](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category%3aDevelopment_Environments) of the NSIS wiki that can point you some alternatives (like adding NSIS support to Eclipse).